# How to use directional data as feature using scikit-learn knn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn, gridsearchcv

I'm new to using KNN and in my train set I have velocity vector. Since the directions 359° and 0° are completely different I was thinking of transforming the direction so that the vector in test data it points to 180°.

I could make this transformation before using KNeighborsClassifier if I predict from one data point, but when I tune the hyperparameters with GridSearchCV the transformation should be done between every comparison. Is there some way to do that?

Or some alternative way that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can break direction column, `theta` into **2 columns, `sin(theta)` and `cos(theta)`**, both of which would have continuity.

Comment: Thank you, great idea. I used this for a while but in my final solution I ended up transforming my data before fitting to cut down one feature.